# ASP.net using label.Text in select query

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have to run a SQL query using a text value in a label and then run that query and bind data to a gridview. Here's my code in VB.net

```
Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection

Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter

Dim details As New DataSet

Dim detailcmd As New SqlCommand("select student_name,student_id from students where student_name = '" + snamelabel.Text + "'", myConnection)


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ad.SelectCommand = detailcmd
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial  Catalog=students;Integrated Security=True"
    myConnection.Open()
    ad.Fill(details, "Details")
    myConnection.Close()

    DetailGridView.DataSource = details
    DetailGridView.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I get the following error message for the SqlCommand  --->

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is the data binding for grid view correct?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- This line will cause sql Injection in the future.

```
Dim detailcmd As New SqlCommand(
"select student_name,student_id from students where student_name = '"
 + snamelabel.Text + "'", myConnection)
```

2- No Need to open/close the connection when use data adapter..

3- I think the error because you are initializing the Command in the class try move it to page load event.